# Change File extensions for entire folder

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script where all the file extensions are changed from .bmp to .jpg. There have been some helpful answers I have found but I still can't get my script to work. If anyone had any suggestions on what I might need to change, it would be greatly appreciated. The script doesn't come up with any errors but none of the file extensions in the folder change.

```
import os, glob, sys
folder = '\\stsosage\...\LegalCardsTest'
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, '*.bmp')):
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.jpg')
```

Comment: You could just call out to the shell with a mv command, mv foo.bmp foo.jpg

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do that, but thank you for responding

Comment: `print folder` should give you a hint. (See e.g. [here](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/))

Comment: More specifically - `use folder = r'\\stsosage\..`

Comment: Try [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) prior to the loop to change to the relevant directory. Or, add the path prior to renaming.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import os

def walk_dir(targetdir,topdown=True):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(targetdir, topdown):
        for name in files:
            os.rename(targetdir+name, targetdir+name.replace(".bmp",".jpg"))

walk_dir(FOLDER_PATH_END_WITH_\)
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code:

```
import os
os.chdir(input("Enter dir: "))
endv = input("File extension before: ")
endn = input("File extension after: ")
for s in os.listdir(pfad):
  if "."+endv in s:
    try:os.rename(s,s.replace("."+endv,"."+endn)
    except BaseException e:print(e)
```

Hope it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

filename is only the file name and not the entire path that you need to provide to you mv function.

Try to concat folder with filename in your mv command.